# CSS background overlay color issue with padding

Tags: css, background-image, overlay

I would like to ask a small help because I can not handle with overlay a div with background. In my website there are welcome section which is 100% width and 100% height, it has a background image which is covered a small texture pattern and rgba color. It works correct but I have a problem with other section which can not be covered by overlay.

The problem is with **"CTA section"** because it use padding (top and bottom). Unfortunately, the whole background of this section is not covered and generally I do not know how I can fix it very simple. I would not use const height property because I want to create something which will match to content of section (all content in this section should be centered vertical and horizontal and also works in smaller devices, so padding is fine).

Well, I am wondering if you could help me with it because I really do not know how to code it or even rebuild it.

Here you can see a demo: http://codepen.io/testerius/pen/viryc

That's all. Hope you answer soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need to change the CSS for the CTA section to what I updated your codepen to here >> [**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/amir5000/pen/pzuwk)

Let me know if that is what you need.

Comment: Oh, hi, well I am not sure if you send me a updated project, because I see any changes there. CTA section is not covered by pattern/color (whatever you call it), here is a pic: http://i.imgur.com/I0nLJ8Y.png

Comment: not problem, I really happy that you're helping me but what you created it isn't not what I expected. :P Hmmm, let me explain what I really want to do for CTA section: http://i.imgur.com/3IbyEwz.png CTA won't be 100% height, only welcome (WE ARE FLATRIX) should be 100%. I'm so sorry for my grammar of you couldn't understand me.

Comment: Ok I updated the CodePen, you can change the padding to whatever you want it to be and change it for mobile using media queries if needed

Comment: Ok, well it looks better than previous fixes but it is not exactly that how it should look (text it's not centered vertical). It seems to me I will have to change code and make separately pattern/color for welcome section and CTA section. I will not torment you more (sorry! :P) and thank you very much for that you tried help me a bit. Have a nice day/night.

Answer (score 0):

Try use same padding for `.section-pattern-overlay` and remove padding from `.cta`

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not 100% sure that I understand you.

Comment: Hmmmmm, I tested it a while ago and it can not help me, as you can see welcome section uses overlay too, so it can not use padding.

Comment: Then remove absolute positioning of section-center?